# find the equation of the tangent line to the curve y=x^4-6x and perpendicular to the line x-2y+6=0

Tags: calculus, derivatives

this is all I got right now:
$y=x^4-6x$
$y'=4x^3-6$

$x-2y+6=0$
$y=(1/2)x+3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

- The given line has slope $1/2$. If we want our tangent line to be perpendicular to it, then the slope (call it $m$) of the tangent line should be its negative reciprocal.
- It turns out that there is only one value of $x$ where the slope of a tangent line to the given curve happens to equal $m$. Let $x_0$ be this value, and solve for $x_0$ by setting $y'(x_0) = m$.
- Compute $y(x_0)$ to get its corresponding $y$-coordinate, $y_0$.
- Use the point-slope formula:
  $$
  y - y_0 = m(x - x_0)
  $$

Answer (score 0):

The tangent line to any point $\;(a,f(a))\;$ on the graph of $\;f(x)=x^4-6x\;$ is

$$y-f(a)=f'(a)(x-a)\iff y-f(a)=(4a^3-6)(x-a)$$

Since the slope of $\;x-2y+6=0\;$ is $\;\frac12\;$ , we need that the tangent's slope to be $\;-2\;$ :

$$4a^3-6=-2\iff a^3\iff a^3=1$$

Finish the argument .